# How to count factors in a cell by using R?

Tags: r

I am new to R, can anybody help me write code to answer this simple question in R?

I have ten numbers in one cell which has "376255 428765 462200 487875 706045 1411535 1452311 1648377 1840213 2021740". How do I count these numbers?

Comment: Those are not "numbers" ("digits" perhaps, but they are of mode character) and R does not have cells. Learn to use terminology properly and you will be able to understand the help pages better.

Answer (score 1):

```
n <- "376255 428765 462200 487875 706045 1411535 1452311 1648377 1840213 2021740"

length(unlist(strsplit(n, " ")))
[1] 10
```

Comment: +1 for your mind-reading skills. Maybe throw a `unique` in there.

Comment: @flodel The other thing it could be would be to count the frequency of each number, hence `table` might be appropriate.